# Argument 1 has unexpected type 'set' Error using processing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator, qgis-processing

I am currently working on a code that adds a field to a shapefile and inputs its filepath. I understand that the processing.run has changed from qgis 2 to qgis 3 but I am not sure why I am getting this error. Below is the code that I am working on.

```
enter code here
from qgis.core import *
import sys
import glob, os, shutil, time, string
import qgis.utils
import processing
from qgis.analysis import *

Location = r"\shapefile"


for root,d_names,f_names in os.walk(Location):
    for f in f_names:

        if f.endswith('.shp'):
            if ".kml" in f:
            continue
            src = os.path.join(root,f)
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(src, f, "ogr")
            param = {layer, 'Filepath' , 2 , 150 ,0 , True, root, src}
```

This is the error I get:

TypeError: QgsProcessingAlgorithm.parameterAsBool(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'set'

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

You're passing processing.run a [python `set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of a `dict`.

Instead of:

```
param = {layer, 'Filepath' , 2 , 150 ,0 , True, root, src}
processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', param)
```

Use something like:

```
param = {
'INPUT': layer, 'FIELD_NAME': 'Filepath', 'FIELD_TYPE': 2 , FIELD_LENGTH': 150 ,'FIELD_PRECISION': 0 , 
'NEW_FIELD':True, 'FORMULA': 'Your calculator expression', 'OUTPUT':'your output file'}
processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', param , feedback=feedback, context=context)
```

Comment: That is good to know, thank you very much. I am still having the same error as before though. I updated the code to match what I have now.

Comment: @Apmartin You still have the original `param = {layer, 'Filepath' , 2 , 150 ,0 , True, root, src}` in there which is causing the same error.

Comment: ok that was silly of me. Thank you for pointing that error to me. I changed the post back to the original post. One more question, what is the use of "feedback=feedback" and "context=context"? I get the error that they are not defined. Am I supposed to import another library for that?

Comment: @Apmartin you can remove them if you're running a standalone script.  If you're writing a processing plugin algorithm, those variables will get passed to the `processAlgorithm` method of your algorithm class and then you can pass them to the processing.run function.